# pandas_datareader ImportError: cannot import name string_types

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
```

I installed pandas_datareader via pip and it all success.

When i try to run a simple code, i got below error:

```
"C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Yahoo.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Yahoo.py", line 1, in <module>

import pandas_datareader as pdr

  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo, get_data_enigma,  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in <module>

    from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\google\daily.py", line 1, in <module>

    from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader

  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 7, in <module>

    import pandas.compat as compat
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *

  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 14, in <module>

    from pandas.core.series import Series, TimeSeries

  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 35, in <module>

    from pandas.compat.scipy import scoreatpercentile as _quantile
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\scipy.py", line 5, in <module>

    import numpy as np

  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>

    from pandas.compat import string_types, string_and_binary_types
ImportError: cannot import name string_types

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have Python 2.7 version adn Windows 7 64 bit system.

Is the process of installation issue?

Comment: Pandas version?

Comment: I think datareader is not installed as part of conda (presuming you got pandas through Anaconda, judging by file links). See this [link](http://www.phillipburger.net/wordpress/pandas-datareader-package-importerror/) which has a potential solution (not exact to your one, but could help.) You could also try doing pip install --upgrade pandas

Comment: It is the version issue. I upgrade the conda and it works

Answer (score 0):

conda version issue. Need to upgrade conda version